# JAX-RS PathSegment @PathParam error in Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, rest, jersey, jax-rs

Eclipse gives the following error when I add the `@PathParam` annotation for a `PathSegment` parameter

> The type `javax.ws.rs.core.PathSegment` is not valid for this parameter. See JAX-RS 2.0 Specification (section 3.2) for more
> information.

```
@GET
@Path("{var1:customers}/{var2:orders}/{month}")
public String getMonthOrders(@PathParam("var1") PathSegment customerPs, // error
                             @PathParam("var2") PathSegment orderPs,    // error
                             @PathParam("month") String month) {
      
     String info = String.format(
             "resource getMonthOrders(). Customers Matrix Param: %s," +
             " Orders Matrix Param: %s, month :%s%n",
             customerPs.getMatrixParameters(),
             orderPs.getMatrixParameters(), month);
      
     return info;
}
```